# Change attached property from CustomPanel doesn't refresh panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, propertychanged

I created dummy custom panel `ShelfPanel` with attached property `Exact` influence panel arrange:

```
class ShelfPanel : Panel
{
    #region Start attached property
    public static DependencyProperty ExactProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Exact", typeof(int), typeof(ShelfPanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | // Does this options have auto action?
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)); // Does this options have auto action?

    public static void SetExact(UIElement element, int value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ExactProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetExact(UIElement element)
    {
        return (int)element.GetValue(ExactProperty);
    }
    #endregion

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size final = new Size();
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            final.Height += child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }
        return final;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            Point position = new Point();
            int exact = ShelfPanel.GetExact(child);
            // Calculate position based on attached Exact
            position.X = exact * 100;
            position.Y = exact * 100;
            child.Arrange(new Rect(position, child.DesiredSize));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

```
<local:ShelfPanel>
     <local:Box local:ShelfPanel.Exact="0" MouseDown="Box_MouseDown"/>
     <local:Box local:ShelfPanel.Exact="1" />
     <local:Box local:ShelfPanel.Exact="2" />
</local:ShelfPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window // Codebehind for previous xaml
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Box_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // I certainly sure this code get triggered after click.
        ShelfPanel.SetExact(sender as UIElement, 3); 
    }
}
```

This works perfect `<local:Box>` are arranged as planned.
As you can deduce from code, after click on first `<local:Box>` it should change it position to 3, just after others 2. But surprisingly nothing happen.

Doesn't `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Affects Arrange` or `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender` automatically repaint panel? 
To make this works I need to add `PropertyChangedCallback`and call there `InvalidateVisual()`?

Comment: You are setting the attached property on a Box, but want the parent element of the Box, i.e. the ShelfPanel to be arranged. Try `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange`.

Comment: @Clemens You Sir, are a genius. of course change you propose resolved the issue.
Could you please write it as answer, hence I will we able to accept it for other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the attached property on a Box, but want the parent element of the Box, i.e. the ShelfPanel to be arranged.

You should therefore set `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ExactProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Exact", typeof(int), typeof(ShelfPanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange));
```

Comment: The problem is cause by me and DOC's (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) which isn't precisly about this. In remarks there should be paragraph about `AffectsArrange` vs `AffectsParentArrange`. e.g: Remember that options refers to element on which property is attached not the owner. This is particularly important for `Attached Property`. Of course I give feedback there, but don't expects changes.

Comment: IMO it's obvious that options like AffectsArrange have an effect only on the element where the property is set. If the parent element should be affected, you'd obviously set the appropriate AffectsParent... options.

Comment: We differ here, but okay :D. I Am rookie maybe that's why.